# how to use try and catch block in java

Tags: java, try-catch

I am using java and I have a file which has some numbers.

> 1 2
>
> 3 4

I want to read this file and store it in a 2d array. But there could also be letter or doubles, in which case I want to print error in a try/catch block. Below is my code, which produces an error when it finds a letter or a double.

> 1 2.3
>
> a 4

```
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    for (int y = 0; y < a.length; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < a[y].length; x++) {
            a[y][x] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Another error I want to check in try/catch block is the wrong size. Below is an example of this input. You can see it will not fit in a 2d array. In that case I want to print the error in a try/catch block

> 1 2 3
>
> 4 5

Comment: possible duplicate of [Try/catch in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068186/try-catch-in-java)

Comment: this is not what I want.

Comment: Your question is "how to use try/catch". The linked question answers that question appropriately. If you understand try/catch statements, your specific case becomes trivial.

Comment: Then what **do** you want?

Comment: I dont need "Exception". I need the to check for format and size exception. I tried to put try/catch in my while loop but it doesn't catch it

Comment: @jhon Can I know why you have unaccepted my answer? Is it something wrong with it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate both catch blocks. You need to use [InputMismatchException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html) to know if the value that you are retrieveing it's an int and [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) to see if you are trying to access to a wrong size of your array:

```
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    for (int y = 0; y < a.length; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < a[y].length; x++) {
           try{
               a[y][x] = sc.nextInt();
           }catch(InputMismatchException ex){
               System.out.println("The format of the number it's not correct");
           }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
               System.out.println("You are trying to access to a wrong index of the array");
           }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try/catch blocks are used for exception handling.Exception and error are two different things.Exception is any unwanted result to programmer/user not necessary an error.

The set of code prone to exception is written in try block and the handling of exception is done inside catch block by writing appropriate catch clause.
When an exception is occurred in any statement inside try block object of that exception is generated and control of execution is headed to corresponding catch block of matching exception i.e matching parameter to that of generated exception object.

```
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                for (int y = 0; y < a.length; y++) {
                    for (int x = 0; x < a[y].length; x++) {
                        try{
                              a[y][x] = sc.nextInt();
                           }
                        catch(Exception e){
                             e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I have written general catch block which catches object of type Exception i.e the top most class in hierarchy of exceptions.In your scenario,the exception name is NumberFormatException and ArrayIndexOutOfBound for invalid array size.