# Quartz scheduler not executing the SQL Query in a dropwizard application

Tags: java, sql-server, database, quartz-scheduler, dropwizard

I've an application created using dropwizard framework where I've registered a quartz-scheduler job scheduled to run after every specified duration. This job fires a SQL query to SQL Server DB and iterates the ResultSet and sets the data to a POJO class which is later pushed to a queue.

The SQL query has UNION joining multiple tables which fetches the data for the records modified in a delta time using the last_modified_time column of the related table in where clause. DB jar included in pom.xml is sqljdbc-4.4.0 and quartz version is 2.2.1

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    u.last_modified_date, 
    u.account_id, 
    u.user_id, 
    ud.is_active 
FROM user u WITH (NOLOCK) 
JOIN user_details ud with (NOLOCK) ON u.account_id = ud.account_id AND u.user_id = ud.user_id 
WHERE u.last_modifed_date > ? AND ud.last_modifed_date <= ?

UNION

SELECT 
    u.last_modified_date, 
    u.account_id, 
    u.user_id, 
    ud.is_active 
FROM user u WITH (NOLOCK) 
JOIN user_details ud with (NOLOCK) ON u.account_id = ud.account_id AND u.user_id = ud.user_id 
JOIN user_registration_details urd WITH (NOLOCK) ON urd.account_id = u.account_id AND urd.user_id = u.user_id AND urd.reg_id = ud.reg_id
WHERE urd.last_modifed_date > ? AND urd.last_modifed_date <= ?
```

This query is called by simple connection statement and resultset like this

```
final ManagedDataSource datasource configuration.getDatabase().build(environment.metrics(), "sql");
// configuration is the configuration class in a drop wizard application and configuration.getDatabase() returns 
// the DataSourceFactory with all credentials like user, password and url set into it
try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection()) {
      int resultSetType = SQLServerResultSet.TYPE_SS_SERVER_CURSOR_FORWARD_ONLY;
      int resultSetConcurrency = ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY;
      LOGGER.info("Starting execution: ");
      try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(getQuery(), resultSetType,resultSetConcurrency))
      {
         setQueryParameters(pstmt);
         try (ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();) 
         {
           //process results 
         }
     }
  } catch (SQLException | IOException ex) {
        LOGGER.error(“Error occurred “ +  ex);
}
LOGGER.info("Completed execution: ");
```

In a simple execution, it prints the logs "Starting execution" and then processes the records and prints "completed execution". But sometimes during the execution, it's printing the logs "Starting execution" and "completed execution" but this query is not actually fired to the SQL DB.

As I didn't get the records which I modified in that delta time, I put the profiler to check if the query is actually fired and didn't found this query firing to the DB. Also, I've tried adding log4jdbc library http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/wiki/FAQ to print the query to the logs but no logs were printed for this query.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer - Though I read all do's and don'ts while posting this, I forgot to go through this section. I'll take care of this next time I post a question.

Comment: I've not posted much on stackoverflow before, so can someone suggest if I need to enter any more information to get some suggestions or answers for this.

Comment: It's been a while since I did much Java, but that `try`-`catch` format does not look right. You're using `try (statement) { statement } catch { statement }`. However, I think it should just be `try { statement } catch { statement }` - I think the round brackets are wrong. [See this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068186/try-catch-in-java) - does your version even compile?

Comment: Your inner `try` also does not have a `catch` (as well as having the round brackets).

Comment: @halfer - This is a syntax of try-with-resources where in any object that implements java.lang.AutoCloseable interface can be initialized in this format. Using this way, it automatically takes care to invoke the close() method on the created instance so we don't need to explicitly write the closing statements in finally block.

Comment: Also, in case the immediate inner try block or any sub try blocks throws an SQLException or IOException, it'll be caught by the outer catch and any other exception will be thrown to the calling method which will be printed to stacktrace as I'm not suppressing the exception.

Comment: Eh?  `with (NOLOCK)` is not MySQL syntax??

Comment: @Aman, pro tip: when you have a bounty live on Stack Overflow, it's worth signing in every day, and continuing your research in parallel, and making updates to your post. You've not logged in for four days, so this bounty has been somewhat wasted. I don't mind that personally, but from your side, it depends on whether you actually want an answer `:-)`. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

`with (NOLOCK)` is not MySQL syntax.  Look at the settings in the wizard and see if you have specified the correct RDBMS engine.  In particular, it sounds like SQL Server syntax.

The equivalent may involve setting the `TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL` to something like `READ UNCOMMITTED`.

Comment: My bad, this is SQL server. I've changed the tag and description. But I think this can't effect/block the execution of this query to DB.

Comment: @Aman: have you tried running the query manually inside your SQL Server client, to see if there are any problems running it?

Comment: @halfer, Yes, I tried running it in SQL server and there are no issues with the query.

Comment: @Aman: I would advise you to be more active on this question if you can - are you researching it in parallel? The bounty will expire in three days, so if you can add more logs or whatever, now is the time to do it!

Comment: @halfer - Thanks for your help ! I was doing research in parallel but couldn't update, my bad.
I checked if query was caching data at the session level but it wasn't happening. Then yesterday, I enabled all mybatis logs and used the spy sqljdbc driver to print all logs at db and at request level.
I was scratching my head to the logs and observed some months old wierd logs of the same application deployed on another server months ago. Multiple application instances were running in the same environment is the issue it was skipped by this application instance.
I think we can close this issue.

Comment: @Aman: is that worth a self-answer, Aman? Questions are only closed here if they're off-topic, and it sounds like you have an answer...

Answer (score 0):

I turned the SQL Profiler on this query and filtered it for my server to check if the query was actually hitting the DB from my application and found that the profiler could only find it rarely hitting the DB. So, I thought there might be some caching happening at mybatis level. Then I added more logs and performed debug analysis on mybatis by enabling all kind of logging and to check if there are any caching at local level or second level cache [mybatis configuration](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html) but that wasn't the cause. 
Then I used spy jdbc driver [log4jdbc driver](https://code.google.com/archive/p/log4jdbc/downloads) to log all the queries, parameters and all db information requests at db level.

My organization is using Spunk application to display logs from all the applications deployed to the different host servers. While checking the logs in splunk, I observed the same query was printed twice in the logs but when I noticed deeply it was printing one from my instance and another execution from the different instance deployed on some other server. I logged in to that server and found the same application deployed over there not updated since months. It was found to be multiple application instances running in the same environment but on two different servers and there is no way I could figure out that an application was deployed on multiple hosts.

Thank you @halfer for all the help and bounty.